# Why does my document.getElementsByClassName("obj").innerHTML doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace HTML in document with .innerHTML but for some reason it doesn't work:

### HTML

```
<div class="specs">
    <div class="wrapp">
        <p class="line">Content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
document.getElementsByClassName("specs").innerHTML = "<p>Lorem ipsum</p>";
```

Comment: "[The `getElementsByClassName` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) of Document interface returns an __array-like object__ of all __child elements__ which have all of the given class name(s). "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection. Not a single item.

There are multiple ways to do this:
You can run a for loop over the returned items.

```
let specs = document.getElementsByClassName("specs");
for(let i = 0 ; i < specs.length;i++){
specs[i].innerHTML = "<p>Lorem ipsum</p>";
}
```

If you have only item, you can use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which returns the first matched element.

```
document.querySelector(".specs").innerHTML = "<p>Lorem ipsum</p>";
```

Answer (score 1):

In a concise way this is how you'd do it

```js
const targets = document.getElementsByClassName("specs")

if (targets.length)
  for (spec in targets)
    targets[spec].innerHTML = "<p>Lorem ipsum</p>";
```

```html
<div class="specs">
  <div class="wrapp">
    <p class="line">Content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found your mistake.

**document.getElementsByClassName** returns an array of elements with the given class name. so try this.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("specs")[0].innerHTML = "<p>Lorem ipsum</p>";
```

For example if you have two elements with the same class name it returns an array containing both the elements, so you have to get the element using the specified index from the array.

Comment: It's not a proper array - it's only "array-like".

Comment: any how it is an array of HTMLElement.

Comment: No it is not @Coder_Naveed. There are subtle differences. Check the MDN Docs

Comment: is the way in which i have did is wrong? it is working. I think the way i call it is wrong.