# Cannot figure out why my JS script will not trigger

Tags: javascript

I'm relatively new to JS so it might be blatantly obvious so I do apologize

I've written a small function that generates a random hexcode to apply against a html class,  but it just won't initialize.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
</head>
    

<body onload="get_random_color()">

    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas mollis.</p>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas mollis.</p>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas mollis.</p>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas mollis.</p>
    <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas mollis.</p>

    <script language="javascript">
        var rand = document.getElementsByClassName("para");

        function get_random_color(){
            
            var letters ='0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
            var color = '#';
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15  )];
            }
            return color;

            rand.style.backgroundColor = get_random_color();

        }


    </script>
    
</body>
```

Any insights or help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

J

Comment: [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an "array-like" HTML collection. You need to iterate over that collection, and then apply the color to each element.

Comment: Checkout : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69423496/why-does-my-document-getelementsbyclassnameobj-innerhtml-doesnt-work/69423514#69423514 https://stackoverflow.com/a/69423514/10140124

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gather up the paragraphs by class using [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), iterate over them and apply a new color to each by calling the function.

```js
const paras = document.querySelectorAll('.para');

paras.forEach(para => para.style.color = get_random_color());

function get_random_color() {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
  }
  return color;
}
```

```html
<p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas mollis.</p>
<p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas mollis.</p>
<p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas mollis.</p>
<p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas mollis.</p>
<p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas mollis.</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have many issue with the code.

- Your `body onload` calls `get_random_color`, which correctly generates the `color`, but you then have a `return` which prevents it from being assigned to the style in the following line.
- Variable `rand` is assigned not one element but a collection of elements. See the documentation of `getElementsByClassName`. Even if your `return` wasn't there, the collection does not have a style property. You have to set the style on each element using a `for` loop.
- Inside the `get_random_color` function, the `rand.style.backgroundColor = get_random_color();` calls itself - if `return` wasn't there, you'd get a stack overflow because the method would call itself over and over.
- In general, always name your identifiers (like functions and variables) to fit their purpose. The variable `rand` is misnamed - it should be `paragraphs` or something like that.